# Armadillo : Can not find clapack.h

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to install Armadillo [link](http://arma.sourceforge.net/).

However, make command **complains about "clapack.h"** which **does exists at location /usr/include/atlas/clapack.h**.  Some help would be appreciated.

Note, I **can run** it if I copy that file to /usr/include/ and then make:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/include/atlas/clapack.h /usr/include/
$ make
```

But, I am not comfortable in making copies of same file in multiple location. **Could it be dangerous?**

This is what I did so far:

1) I downloaded and tar the armadillo library. After that, I changed following lines in CMakeLists.txt (I have Lapack, Blas, Atlas):

```
set(ARMA_USE_LAPACK    true)
set(ARMA_USE_BLAS      true)
set(ARMA_USE_ATLAS     true)
set(ARMA_USE_HDF5_ALT  false)
set(ARMA_USE_ARPACK    false)
set(ARMA_USE_CXX11_RNG false)
set(ARMA_USE_WRAPPER   true )
```

then "`$cmake .`" runs successfully and finds `Lapack, Blas and Atlas`.
However, when I run "`make`" it gives following error (**line 26 marked in the code include_atlas.hpp**):

```
$ make

Scanning dependencies of target armadillo
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o
In file included from /home/dkumar/Downloads/armadillo-4.600.3/src/wrapper.cpp:10:0:
/home/dkumar/Downloads/armadillo-4.600.3/tmp/include/armadillo_bits/include_atlas.hpp:26:47: fatal error: /usr/include/clapack.h: No such file or directory
       #include ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(ARMA_CLAPACK)
                                               ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When I look at `include_atlas.hpp`, it seems that `ARMA_USE_ATLAS` is still set false:

```
// Copyright (C) 2008-2011 Conrad Sanderson
// Copyright (C) 2008-2011 NICTA (www.nicta.com.au)
// 
// This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
// License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
// file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.


#if defined(ARMA_USE_ATLAS)
  #if !defined(ARMA_ATLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)
    extern "C"
      {
      #include <cblas.h>
      #include <clapack.h>
      }
  #else
    #define ARMA_STR1(x) x
    #define ARMA_STR2(x) ARMA_STR1(x)

    #define ARMA_CBLAS   ARMA_STR2(ARMA_ATLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)ARMA_STR2(cblas.h)
    #define ARMA_CLAPACK ARMA_STR2(ARMA_ATLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)ARMA_STR2(clapack.h)

    extern "C"
      {
      #include ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(ARMA_CBLAS)
      #include ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(ARMA_CLAPACK)      // This is line no 26
      }

    #undef ARMA_STR1
    #undef ARMA_STR2
    #undef ARMA_CBLAS
    #undef ARMA_CLAPACK
  #endif
#endif
```

If I replace `ARMA_CLAPACK` with `"/usr/include/atlas/clapack.h"`, it still complains:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target armadillo
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o
In file included from /home/dkumar/Downloads/armadillo-4.600.3/src/wrapper.cpp:10:0:
/home/dkumar/Downloads/armadillo-4.600.3/tmp/include/armadillo_bits/include_atlas.hpp:26:89: fatal error: "/usr/include/atlas/clapack.h": No such file or directory
    #include ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP("/usr/include/atlas/clapack.h")      // This is line no 26
                                                                                         ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Don't modify `CMakeLists.txt`. Instead, use the original one that comes with Armadillo, and let cmake detect whether Atlas is present or not.

Comment: @mtall I did that. I still get the same error.

Comment: You can use Armadillo without installing it.  See the command line shown in point (2) at http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html   Try it without atlas first (ie. only blas and lapack). Once that works, add `-DARMA_USE_ATLAS -I path_to_atlas_include_dir -latlas` to the command line.  Change `path_to_atlas_include_dir` to the directory which contains the `cblas.h` and `clapack.h` headers

Comment: btw, rather than using Atlas, it might be easier to use [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/).  It's an optimized version of BLAS.

Comment: I've generally found Armadillo's CMake configuration to be spotty at best when it comes to detecting libraries.  I often have to dive into the `cmake_aux` and add additional paths as otherwise it would fail to find them in the right places.

Comment: Also, make sure `/usr/include/atlas` is in `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having same problem while running `make` after `cmake .` when I check the `cmake` output it was pointing to wrong atlas directory i.e. it was pointing to `ATLAS_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/` where as it should have been pointing to `ATLAS_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/atlas`.

```
-- Found ATLAS: /usr/lib/libatlas.so
-- Found BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas.so
-- Found LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so
--      MKL_FOUND = NO
--   ACMLMP_FOUND = NO
--     ACML_FOUND = NO
-- OpenBLAS_FOUND = NO
--    ATLAS_FOUND = YES
--     BLAS_FOUND = YES
--   LAPACK_FOUND = YES
-- ATLAS_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/
-- ARPACK_FOUND = NO
-- 
-- *** Armadillo wrapper library will use the following libraries:
-- *** ARMA_LIBS = /usr/lib/libatlas.so;/usr/lib/libblas.so;/usr/lib/liblapack.so
```

I correct this by adding correct path in `CmakeCache.txt` file. After that it `make` and `make install` run fine.

But I am having this error while running after compiling example using

```
g++   -O2   -o example1  example1.cpp  -larmadillo
```

the error is

```
./example1: error while loading shared libraries: libarmadillo.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Note:** The above error can be solved by creating a symbolic link of `libarmadillo.so` and `libarmadillo.so.4` in `/usr/lib` directory.

Comment: Where did `libarmadillo.so` get installed to?  The error you see is because you did not add the directory of `libarmadillo.so` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

Comment: Yes you are rite I could have added it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. By default the installation directory was /usr/local/lib

Comment: Libraries that are compiled by hand (rather than installed via the package manager) go to `/usr/local/lib` by convention, so it's useful to add `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.